# What will happen if I rename a file in XCODE?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

If I rename files,in my XCode[3.2.5] project,
Will its imports and connections with xib's automatically be updated or I will have to make changes everywhere manually.

I was learning iphone development and I didnt give proper names to my controllers according to standard conventions.
Now I am making the changes.

Comment: try to **refactor** instead of a simple rename. Select a class name (in interface) and from the contextual menu, choose `Refactor -> Rename`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the refactoring tools. I can't remember what these were like in 3.2.5 but they'll do the job in 4.2, and you should be on the newest version anyway.

Comment: Actually I am a trainee in my company and they want us to first work on xcode 3.2.x so that we understand the difference between interface builder, simulator and the editor.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, but then that's corporate decision making for you!